# How to show Total Sale value Bar chart or any visual in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Can anybody please help me in getting Total Sale in one bar in Bar Chart visual as show below in picture.

I have calculated total in dataset only just to show the example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unlike with a table or matrix visual, to get a total on a bar chart you have to do it manually by creating a new table to use as your axis and a new measure to switch between the total and the parts.

See [this community post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Possible-Analytics-function-dynamic-Total-column-in-chart-with/m-p/366010#M165562) for example.

Here's how you can create a new table to use as your axis:

```
ChartAxis = UNION ( VALUES ( Sales[City] ), ROW ( "City", "All" ) )
```

You'll also need a new measure to put on the chart:

```
SalesByCity =
VAR AxisCity = SELECTEDVALUE ( ChartAxis[City] )
RETURN
    IF (
        AxisCity = "All",
        SUM ( Sales[Sales] ),
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( Sales[Sales] ), Sales[City] = AxisCity )
    )
```

Comment: This will shop up the total sales of  either All city or Selected city right?

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to ask.