# PBI - add total bar

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have **chart** with:

1. **y-axis**: sales in euro and
2. **x-axis**: month.

I'm trying to add a new bar with total (months). I have the following chart:

[image]

and I want to create a new bar with total

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61784994

Comment: @AlexisOlson Flag as duplicate?

Comment: Thanks , but I'm looking for solution in the same array. I have so many rows with data.

Comment: You can't have a category on the axis that doesn't exist in your table column.

Comment: Thanks. Because there is no solution without creating a table. I should create next to month diagram, a new one diagram with x-axis:year and y-axis:euro.